# Is it possible to access DOM and manipulate it out of render method in react?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I want to use react as a js library injected into my html page. like JQuery, to access DOM and manipulate it. In Vue.js we can do this but in react I doubt it works. I can't access DOM out of react Component and render method.I want a solution to access elements out of render method

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of ref callback to access the dom element in react, which is what React Docs recommend to follow..

[DOCS](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: It give access only on those elements created in the render method. I want a solution to access elements out of render method

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain native JavaScript, for eg. `document.querySelector()` in any lifecycle function of React as well as in `render()`.

Can you give an example of what you're trying to do exactly?